# 15-year-old fridge goes "clunk" at end of cycle

Tags: refrigerator, noise, noise-reduction, compressor

Started happening a few years ago, unclear whether it has gotten any louder or whether there's anything that makes it better or worse. I don't think it was this bad when new, though.

Functionally, fridge still seems fine. It was off-the-scale efficient when I bought it in 2000; it's probably average or below by today's standards.

I've gotten used to this clunk/thunk/thud noise and mostly don't notice it. I've assumed that it's the compressor being pushed back a bit as power is removed, or something like that. But it occurs to me that one of you might know what it is and whether it can be quieted at all; I now have a guest bedroom next to the kitchen and I'm sure visitors would appreciate not having to hear it hiccup quite so loudly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a broken  or worn-out "vibration damping mount.the inertia of the internal moving parts at shutdown will cause the hole compressor to rotate up off  of the mounting  and slam back as gravity and the rubber nounts return it to its normal position. Common caus of the noise you describe. 
Fix find a similar mount to replace the broken one. At a used appliances store,or appliances disposal site for free,or order from the manufacturer.
  Gumby stay flexible.

Comment: Ah; equivalent to wearing out the motor mounts in a car. Makes sense. I'm going to pause to give other folks a chance to weigh in before declaring this answered.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a sign of an internal bearing going bad. A compressor can run like this for years. Amana units were known for it. If it is more than 1 clunk

Comment: Can you finish your post please? I think you accidentally part of it...